# Duo MFA Enrollment API Parameters

Tags: api, websites

Not sure if this is the right forum. I want to enroll my device for Duo MFA without using the Duo app. Duo uses simple HOTP codes, so I used [this](https://github.com/revalo/duo-bypass) script to find the HOTP secret and enter it manually in my preferred authenticator app.

The enrollment succeeds (I see my device in the list of enrolled devices), and the codes generated by the script don't give an "invalid code" error. Instead, they give a "Duo Mobile None is not allowed" error, asking me to upgrade to a newer version of the app.

Obviously I need to pass some API params so Duo thinks I'm running a supported version. However, the Duo API documentation isn't clear on how version, platform, and OS version are reported during enrollment. (In fact, I don't even see documentation for that API - just authentication for an individual user and administration for all users in a company).

The API I'm using is /push/v2/activation/{code}, where {code} is the activation code stored in the enrollment QR code. I've tried adding 'version' (3.33.0.3, 3.33.0, etc.), 'platform' (apple%20ios), and 'type' (tablet) parameters, with those values based on documentation for other APIs. Enrollment succeeds regardless, but I continue to see the "Duo Mobile None is not allowed" message. Looking at the [Python client repo](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_client_python) on Github didn't help me understand how to enroll devices.

If possible I'd like to report the platform as Apple iOS, but another solution might be imitating a hardware token or the generic_smartphone type mentioned in the other API docs.

Can someone with more experience than me suggest a way to discover the correct API parameter names and values, or some other way to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems more relevant to contact Duo or their support for this kind of issue.
In any case, it does not seem to fit this forum. Good luck!